# How to add a new button in title bar next the minimize button in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, button, uwp, titlebar

I want to add a new button in the title bar of a UWP application, something that looks like this :

[image: Exemple]

I have already saw some "similar" posts but the answers aren't really clear and it lacks details, it's hard for me to understand what they have done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

by default UWP  does not have the ability to add buttons to the titlebar. But uwp support custom titlebar layout.

**For starting hide title bar view**

```
CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
```

**After Create new grid layout and attach it to title bar**

```
Window.Current.SetTitleBar(UserLayout);
```

Create `TitleBar` and subscribe `LayoutMetricsChanged` event that uses to  dynamically create Margin, because with a different number of system buttons it will be different.

```
var tBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
tBar.LayoutMetricsChanged += OnTitleBarLayoutMetricsChanged;
```

**And add function**

```
public void OnTitleBarLayoutMetricsChanged(CoreApplicationViewTitleBar sender, object args)
{
    var bar = sender as CoreApplicationViewTitleBar;
    RightPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, bar.SystemOverlayRightInset, 0);
}
```

Navigate page frame to home page

```
Content.Navigate(typeof(Home), null, new SuppressNavigationTransitionInfo()); // Navigate to Home page with null args and null animation
```

End in app.xaml.cs set standart navigation frame to this page

```
if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false) {
    if (rootFrame.Content == null) {
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(AniMiru.Windows10.Views.AppCustomWindow), e.Arguments);
    }
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

**Page xaml:**

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="TopBar" >
            <Grid x:Name="UserLayout" Background="#00000000" />
            <Grid Canvas.ZIndex="1">
                <StackPanel x:Name="LeftPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <AutoSuggestBox QueryIcon="Find" PlaceholderText="Search" Width="300" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel x:Name="RightPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Button Content="" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="13" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    <Button Content="" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="13" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Frame x:Name="Content" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

**Page C#:**

```
public AppCustomWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    // Hide titlebar panel and add new layout to title bar
    CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
    Window.Current.SetTitleBar(UserLayout);

    // Add LayoutMetricsChanged Event to TitleBar
    var tBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
    tBar.LayoutMetricsChanged += OnTitleBarLayoutMetricsChanged;

    // Navigate
    Content.Navigate(typeof(Home), null, new SuppressNavigationTransitionInfo()); // Navigate to Home page with null args and null animation
}

public void OnTitleBarLayoutMetricsChanged(CoreApplicationViewTitleBar sender, object args)
{
    var bar = sender as CoreApplicationViewTitleBar;
    RightPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, bar.SystemOverlayRightInset, 0);
}
```

**Screenshots:**

[image: Screenshot]

**Urls:**

[Title bar customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/title-bar)

[Layout panels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/layout-panels)

[Handling and raising events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/)

---

Sory for my English.

Best regards.

Comment: Just to add some: There's a small, default dragable area next to the minimize button that you have no option to override it. Please consider that when you are trying to make a custom title bar.