# UWP design custom title-bar

Tags: c#, uwp, titlebar

I designed this title-bar in WPF, but in UWP I don't know how do this.

[image]

I see several link but no one not suitable for me :

1. [UWP quick tip: custom titlebar](https://medium.com/@Niels9001/uwp-quick-tip-custom-titlebar-c196fc56071c) [ github : [BlogTitleBar](https://github.com/niels9001/BlogTitleBar) ]
2. [Title bar customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/title-bar) [ Microsoft ]
3. [How to add a new button in title bar next the minimize button in UWP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57294045/how-to-add-a-new-button-in-title-bar-next-the-minimize-button-in-uwp) [ stackoverflow ]
4. [Customize Title Bar & Add Full Screen Button in UWP](https://ahmedabdelkarim.wordpress.com/2016/10/29/custom-title-bar-with-full-screen-button-in-uwp/)

I want to hide the current title bar and create a new one, I think this method is easier and I have the ability to make any changes; In WPF that was the case.

Answer (score 0):

You set the `CoreApplicationViewTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar` property to `true` and then create your own custom title bar using elements in view as mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/title-bar?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) on the second link.

> When you opt-in to full title bar customization, your app’s client area is extended to cover the entire window, including the title bar area. You are responsible for drawing and input-handling for the entire window except the caption buttons, which are overlaid on top of the app’s canvas.

```
// using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;

// Hide default title bar.
var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
```

Comment: ty for answer, i have several problem with this UWP! 1) pin : we cant pin in UWP! 2) fullscreen : we have 2 button in fullscreen mode!!! 3) It is not possible to edit (move or delete) these 3 buttons [ Close & Minimize & Maximize ] !!! 4) I skipped the two fullscreen/pin buttons and designed [this](https://s16.picofile.com/file/8422284492/Untitled.png)